# Is this possible to find the version of the ofbiz trunk folder version?

Tags: apache, apache2, ofbiz

I have downloaded ofbiz-trunk folder for my ERP project work.I think i downloaded the 9.04 version.Actually downloaded folder has name contains its version.But my colleque has renamed the folder.So, i could not able to identify the version of my ofbiz trunk.Is there any way to find out its version or is it possible at runtime?

Is there any config file that mention the version?

Please guide me to get out of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any config file that contain this information but I was able to determine what version my team was using by downloading the versions (4.0, 9.04, 10.04, 11.04 etc)  and doing a comparison between those and the code we were working on using a standard diff tool.